# Why do links not work when using href and overlays?

Tags: html, css

Been trying to figure this out for a few days now, and absolutely cannot get to the bottom of it. I have an image, a rollover image, and text below. The text links to the new page fine, but the images just refuse to link. I have tried to adjust the z-level, but to no avail. Hoping someone can help out.

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="row" id="societies-cards">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="card-image"><a href="/join/"><img alt="Join" class="card-img-top" src="/join.jpg" /> </a>

<div class="image-overlay"><a href="/join/">&nbsp;</a></div>
<a href="/join/"> </a></div>

<div class="caption">
<h3 class="text-center"><a href="/join/">JOIN</a></h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Above is the html coding for the image - we use the classes to separate where the content is on the page, and the card image is the original image you see. The overlay is then what you get when you move your finger or mouse over the image, with the caption being what appears below. I've changed the links for privacy, but hopefully you get the idea.

Below here, is the CSS that correlates to the image.

```
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                opacity: 0;
                transition: 0.5s ease;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

and

```
                z-index: -1;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #societies-cards .thumbnail .caption {
                background-color: white;
                box-shadow: 0px -8px 10px -1px white;
                z-index: 1;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
```

Thank you for anyone who decides to take a look at this word soup - having to learn everything on the job and as I didn't originally build this page, it's tough trying to figure some things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the anchor-tag is inside the div.image-overlay. instead you should wrap the div.image-overlay with the anchor-tag.

before:

```html
<div class="image-overlay"><a href="/join/">&nbsp;</a></div>
```

after:

```html
<a href="/join/"><div class="image-overlay"></div></a>
```

#### Alternatively

You could wrap the entire html-tree in an anchor-tag. That way you don't have to have multiple anchor-tags inside the "Box".

*You might need to change some CSS to make this work*

```html
<a href="/join/" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="row" id="societies-cards">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img alt="Join" class="card-img-top" src="/join.jpg" />

          <div class="image-overlay"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="caption">
          <h3 class="text-center">JOIN</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```